# How does drone reliance on GPS make it 'semi-stealthy'?

Tags: military, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, gnss, stealth

I saw this [on CNN today](https://us.cnn.com/2021/06/28/politics/us-airstrikes-new-iran-drone-attacks-avoid-surveillance/index.html).

> For months, US intelligence and military personnel in Iraq have been raising alarms about the risk to American forces from these newer, more sophisticated Iranian-made drones. Rather than being guided by a pilot from a remote location, some of these ***small, fixed-wing drones use GPS navigation, making them far less visible to US surveillance systems and impervious to jamming***.

I understand how an independent guidance system is probably jam-proof, but how  does using GPS make the drones less visible? Don't all military drones rely on  GPS?

Comment: Assuming that CNN knows what they're talking about with regard to aviation and military matters is, increasingly, a hit-or-miss proposition. Many of their "journalists" report on things without even considering the (considerable) depths of their own ignorance.

Comment: Assuming that anything said on CNN, or any TV news outlet, is even *vaguely coherent* is a mistake !

Comment: The key bit is: "far less visible to US surveillance systems" - those systems 'look' for Infra-Red and Radio signals, rather than just what the human eye can see.

Comment: "impervious to jamming" Even for CNN that's some pretty incorrect information.

Comment: It’s a rare news article that gets anything right about aviation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For being remotely controlled, drones need to emit and receive a radio signal. If the outgoing signal contains a video feed, it will be high bandwidth and be like a beacon announcing the location of the drone. By pre-programming the flight path and using GPS location fixes, the drone will be passive and not emit radio signals.

Before GPS, high precision navigation needed an active radar system which would scan the surrounding terrain and compare the results with an onboard map. Such navigation systems were [used by cruise missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TERCOM) but, by relying on an actively emitted signal, would announce their presence to suitably tuned receivers.

While it is true that such a passive drone cannot be jammed, it is still possible to [spoof the GPS signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoofing_attack#GPS_spoofing) or to jam the GPS signal itself, leaving the drone navigation system only with [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) in the vicinity of its target. Also, when no communication with the drone is possible, it will only follow a pre-programmed pattern and not be able to respond intelligently to a changed situation. Such spoofing has been [demonstrated by the Iranians in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93U.S._RQ-170_incident) when they diverted a US drone officially flying over Afghanistan and when [misleading tankers in the strait of Hormuz](https://www.gpsworld.com/iran-jams-gps-on-ships-in-strait-of-hormuz/) recently.

Not all drones rely on GPS since there are alternatives ([GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS), [BeiDou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeiDou) or [NavIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Regional_Navigation_Satellite_System)), apart from active systems like Terrain Contour Matching ([TERCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TERCOM)).

Comment: Inertial navigation is probably also a good alternative (especially when worried about interference), but I'm not sure if that is actually used in drones.

Comment: @Bianfable Inertial navigation is the basis of dead reckoning but becomes progressively unreliable with time due to drift. It needs a GPS fix now and then to eliminate drift.

Comment: @Bianfable I would think that yes, because the 1 Hz refresh rate of GPS with random jitter around current position is insufficient for the flight control system so it needs the gyroscopes and accelerometers anyway, but the accuracy won't be good enough for the final targeting.

Comment: @JanHudec there's nothing inherently 1Hz about GPS or any GNSS system, and many receivers offer between 5 and 20 updates per second.

Comment: @Bianfable Older cruise missiles did indeed use inertial navigation. Some were accurate enough to hug the terrain and fly between mountains and hills (indeed some even used the terrain to correct for INS drift). The thing is to get accurate INS is hard.. really hard. But to build something with GPS guidance is easy. I can buy a $40 GPS module today and write a simple Arduino code to fly something to some location over a weekend.

Comment: Spoofing GPS is still easily detected with INS. And even when GPS is spoofed, it needs to be spoofed in a rather specific way, or else it still can be used to correct for INS errors.

Comment: @MSalters For detecting spoofing, your software must anticipate it. The RQ-170 back in 2011 did certainly not. Next, once spoofing is detected, who do you trust? Your INS will still drift and make the navigation unreliable. Once the spoofed signal drones out the real one, you have no GNSS signal you can trust.

Comment: @slebetman Make sure your GPS module doesn't shut itself off because it thinks you're making a cruise missile :)

Comment: So the answer is that's it's not really specific to GPS or GNSSes (a drone using VOR beacons would have the same issue), but it's that a drone with a programmed course is less visible than one with constant communication with a controller.

Comment: @user253751 My government is more likely to shut me down than the GPS module. It has happened before: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Simpson_(blogger)#DIY_Cruise_Missile

Comment: @slebetman Depends how many missiles you build

Comment: @user253751 For xjet/RCModelReviews that number was 1. But he was advertising doing it mainly for the purpose of getting his government to take the threat of DIY missiles seriously (which he both succeeded and failed - the NZ government tried to stop him but to this day there is no law or task force or even a plan to handle a situation of someone building a DIY missile)

Comment: @PeterKämpf or a star shot using a sextant. Not sure if equipment for that exists that's small and light weight enough to fit inside a small to medium sized drone.

Comment: @jwenting yes, on a cloudless day and in still air. I could list all methods but then run the risk of oodles of comments telling me that this is not answering the question. So I decided to stick with GPS and its consequences only.